# Generating info from an image's name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've tried searching for an answer around the web but couldn't find any so apologies in advance..

Let's say I have a folder called '**designs**' with images

```
design1_main_front.png
design1_mockup-black.png
design1_mockup-white.png

design2_main_front.png
design2_mockup-black.png
design2_mockup-yellow.png
design2_mockup-red.png
```

- All I want is to retrieve the ones with '**_front**' one by one and add them to a class
- Add the ones with '**_front**' to an '**img**' tag
- Add the ones with '**mockup**' to  a select-options tag in a way that if I click the dropdown and click on a color's name, the img src changes to the *designx_mockup-"**color**".png*
  (the color name should be retrieved from the image's title)

I hope it was clear enough to understand, I would appreciate your help

Comment: Javascript has no access to the filesystem, so unless you already know the names of the files, there's no way clientside javascript can check the folder and find out for you.

Comment: @adeneo what about jquery? I mean can't I just create a variable to the images path?

Comment: jquery is javascript, (a javascript library)

Answer (score 0):

First start by adding an image element for both of the front images.  Each of the image tags should have an id.

```
<img src="some_image.jpg" id="image_one">
```

Then create a select box and set the value for each option to the file name you want

```
<select onchange="updateImage(this);">
  <option value="design1_mockup-black.png" >Black</option>
</select>
```

The update image function will take in the dom node of the event (the option).  You can then get the value and set the image to the new file.